# Is there a way to remove Soutern Sahara label from map using react-native-map

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I am building a cross-platform application with react-native expo and I am using react-native-maps to display map but I don't want Soutern Sahara to display the map. So guy please how can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the Southern Sahara from being displayed on your React Native Expo application using react-native-maps, you can set the region property of your MapView component to restrict the visible area to your desired location.

Here's an example code snippet that restricts the visible area of the map to a specific region, in this case, a region excluding the Southern Sahara:

````
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Region } from 'react-native-maps';

const region: Region = {
latitude: 25.2,
longitude: 55.3,
latitudeDelta: 20,
longitudeDelta: 20,
};

export default function App() {
return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <MapView region={region} style={styles.map} />
 </View>
);
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
 flex: 1,
},
map: {
 flex: 1,
},
});```
````